# Is there a way of forcing the image function in R not to normalize coordinates?

Tags: r, image, plot, default, axes

When using the `image` function in R it normalized the length of the dimensions of the input matrix so X and Y axes go from 0 to 1.

Is there a way of telling the `image` function not to normalize these numbers?

I need to do so in order to overlay different kinds of data and normalizing all these coordinates into the [0,1] space is very tedious.

EDIT: The answer provided by Greg explains the situation.

Comment: This is neat, but separate out the answer-part from this, and post it as an answer here.

Comment: I don't agree. The credit is for Greg and I see really no improvement on the understanding of the answer by changing the format to an answer. What are the benefits?

Comment: Well, if it pertains to the question (for example, the reproducible example demonstrates the problematic behavior), then it should remain in the question. **But any information that *answers* the question should be an answer**. You can still leave the credit to Greg as before; there's nothing wrong with posting your own solution even in spite of that, but we like to keep things organized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reproducible example would be very helpful here.  Generally if you only give `image` a `z` matrix then the function chooses default x and y values that work, I think this is what you are seeing.  On the other hand if you give `image` an x vector and a y vector then it uses that information to construct the graph.  If the x/y vectors have a length equal to the corresponding dimension of z then those values represent the centers of the rectangles, if x/y is 1 longer than the corresponding dimension of z then they represent the corners of the rectangles.  This gives you a lot of control over the things that you mention.

If this does not answer the question then give us a self contained reproducible example to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my question based on the answer Greg Snow provided in order to follow the best practice of this site as anything that provides information should be an answer.

If you do not provide the `x` nor `y` parameters to the `image()` function, then the range of the axes is from 0 to 1 as in the next example.

```
> image(volcano)
```

[image: plotting an image without x and y parameters]

Then, if you want to locate a point of interest in the matrix in use, for the element of the matrix with [x,y] coordinates of [10,40] you need to do something like:

```
> points(x=10/length(volcano[,1]),y=40/length(volcano[1,]))
```

[image]

If the `x` and `y` parameters are specified, and (as Greg mentioned) they fit the dimensions of the matrix, then the axes will range withing the specified `x` and `y` vectors.

```
> dim(volcano)
[1] 87 61
> image(x=1:87, y=1:61, z=volcano)
```

[image]

```
 > points(10,40)
```

[image]